# What is `:-` doing in `FOO=${BAR:-localhost}`?

Tags: bash, syntax, environment-variables

I can see that the following code is initializing `FOO` to `localhost` if `BAR` is empty, but what's exactly happening with the `:-`? What is it?

Comment: This should help: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html `${parameter:-word}`
_If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If BAR had a non-empty value, FOO would be assigned that value. If not, FOO would be assigned localhost. You can find more ways in [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> ```
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
> Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
> ```